# Regular expression to check for a URL's protocol

Tags: regex

Currently using:

```
@"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

How can i make `http://` not compulsory but if it does exist, it must be written as `http://`

Comment: Note that `(0-9)*` means zero or more repetitions of `0-9` (literally). I think you want `[0-9]*` or `\d*`.

Comment: I'd even say (:[0-9]+)?, as htt p://example.com:/ is not that useful afaik, neither is htt p://example.com:1:2:3:4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/
```

by

```
^(?:(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?
```

Comment: Although the `(?:` did put a smile on my face: not capturing the actual 'http'/ 'https' etc, but stull capturing 'ht' & 's'.

Comment: @Wrikken: Yeah, I know. I did not want to change the capture group numbering, in case the OP relies on it somewhere...